# Email Addresses with Social Logins Uniqueness

Tags: php, google-api, facebook-php-sdk

So over the last couple of days I have been implementing the Facebook and Google OAuth 2 Social Logins for my site.

Everything works great and basically:

- When a user logs in their email address is compared to whats already on DB
- If the email exists the social login is attached to that already existing email and the user logins into their already existing account
- Otherwise a new account is made. (Much like I have noticed it works here)

But here comes the tricky part. Google can have to two domains for emails:

- gmail.com
- googlemail.com

And if the Facebook account was made in `googlemail.com` the Google account (using `gmail`) will not link. Now I have solved the Google to Facebook relation by checking the DB for both `gmail.com` and `googlemail.com` but the problem comes if it is reversed and Facebook is the one who cannot find the address.

I thought I could just add the `gmail.com` and `googlemail.com` check to the facebook login function to check for unqiue email addresses but I am wondering if this might cause a problem I cannot forsee.

Some of the things on my mind are:

- Future compatibility with other APIs etc
- Complexity
- Security? ( I get around this a bit by using the  `verified` flag in the Facebook API )
- Other Email providers that might have the same problems with double email domains pointing to the same account (maybe I would have to write a huge unmantainable list?).

So the question is: is adding a DB clause to find by `gmail.com` and `googlemail.com` to my Facebook login function a bad idea?

Should I just assume `gmail.com` and `googlemail.com` are two separate accounts?

Thanks for your thoughts,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to actually solve this problem by just searching for both `googlemail.com` and `gmail.com` domains in connection with email addresses when the user logs in with Facebook or Google.

This seems to work quite well and is better than normalising and potentially changing the users info to satisfy this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try converting all "googlemail.com" strings to "gmail.com". The concept is if the system finds googlemail, convert it to gmail.

Example:
User enters test@googlemail.com

Algorithm will be:

```
email = "test@googlemail.com"
replace("@googlemail.com","@gmail.com",email )
authenticate(email);
```

Comment: Hmm yes normalise to one domain only, I did think of this too, I might try it, thanks